# how to redirect to a new screen on the button click in the table view in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a table view and added some labels and displaying it, now i need a button in each cell, where on click on the button, it has redirect to the new screen. 
The following is the code which i am trying to redirect,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    vendorsArray = [CommonUserDetails sharedUserDetails].mVendorDictionary;
    NSLog(@"vendorsArray is %@ \n count is %d",vendorsArray,[vendorsArray count]);

    loTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [loTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    loTableView.delegate = self;
    loTableView.dataSource = self;
    loTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:loTableView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

#define L1_TAG 1
#define L2_TAG 2
#define L3_TAG 3
#define L4_TAG 4

- (UITableViewCell *)tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    UILabel* l1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 30)];
    [l1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [l1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    // [l1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    l1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/(CGFloat)255 green:51/(CGFloat)255 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
    [l1 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [l1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
    l1.tag = L1_TAG;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:l1];


    UILabel* l2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20 , 300, 30)];
    [l2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    l2.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    l2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //l2.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/(CGFloat)255 green:102/(CGFloat)255 blue:153/(CGFloat)255 alpha:1.0];
    l2.tag = L2_TAG;
    [l2 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:l2];

    UILabel* l3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 40, 190, 30)];
    [l3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [l3 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    [l3 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    // l3.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/(CGFloat)255 green:102/(CGFloat)255 blue:0/(CGFloat)255 alpha:1.0];
    [l3 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    l3.tag = L3_TAG;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:l3];

    UILabel* l4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 60, 190, 30)];
    [l4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [l4 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    [l4 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    //l4.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/(CGFloat)255 green:51/(CGFloat)255 blue:0/(CGFloat)255 alpha:1.0];
    [l4 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    l4.tag = L4_TAG;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:l4];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(150, 60, 70, 30);
        [button setTitle:@"Pay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(payButton)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UILabel *myl1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:L1_TAG];
    UILabel *myl2 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:L2_TAG];    
    UILabel *myl3 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:L3_TAG];
    UILabel *myl4 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:L4_TAG];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [vendorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myl1.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INo:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"iNo"]];
    myl2.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"vendorName"];
    myl3.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Amount:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"amount"]];
    myl4.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DDate:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"dDate"]];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"count is %d",[vendorsArray count]);
    return [vendorsArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
     return @"Payables";
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100; 
}
-(IBAction) payButton{

    PayDescriptionController *mPayDescriptionController = [[PayDescriptionController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PayDescriptionController" bundle:nil];
    mPayDescriptionController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mPayDescriptionController animated:YES];
}
```

Where i am going wrong in the above code.

Comment: What happens incorrectly with your code?

Comment: I am calling the payButton in the button, which is in the table view, on click of the button it has redirect to the new screen i.e, to payDescriptionController, but it is not showing that page on click of the button.

Comment: Are you sure it is calling `payButton`?  Did you check it with `NSLog` or a breakpoint?

Comment: ya i checked with the NSLog, it was printing in the console on the click of the button.

Comment: Is your nib assigned with the pay description controller

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mPayDescriptionController animated:YES];
```

see ,it is navigating to next view or not !! and if not then may be one of your object is null.